# Testing with OAuth2 and Postman

Tags: zend-framework2, postman, laminas-api-tools

I am using ZF2 Apigility and am working on setting up an OAuth2 workflow for an API I am writing.

So far I can get the following to work:

1. Call the API and get a token

   ```
   {

   "access_token": "62f6109dcbce42b38f9117b21529faf30fc0ee86",
   "expires_in": 3600,
   "token_type": "Bearer",
   "scope": null
   }
   ```

Now I know I need to use this token in the headers of my next request in order to access my API.

I am just not sure how to go about doing this with PostMan?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click on Headers

then add

Authorization

as Header

and

Bearer 62f6109dcbce42b38f9117b21529faf30fc0ee86

as Value

[image]